# Error: Requiring module "node_modules\expo-media-library\build\MediaLibrary.js",

Tags: react-native, expo

I made a react native project using `react-native init newProject` .I wanted to use expo modules in the project in this module so I ran `npx install-expo-modules` to use expo modules after using this command I installed expo module expo-media-library and when I import this

**Error: Requiring module "node_modules\expo-media-library\build\MediaLibrary.js", which threw an exception:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentMediaLibrary.default.MediaType')**

Answer (score 0):

go with npm install expo-media-library or yarn add expo-media-library

Answer (score 0):

try expo upgrade then expo doctor. mine also stucked there for a while. it even causes AppRegistry error that said main is not registered. should've tried with older versions

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by using the below command:

```
npx install-expo-modules@latest
```

this will ask you to update the existing libraries versions, so select y while installing.

which upgraded the gradle version and expo-related dependencies.

post-installation removed **node_modules** and **Pods** & **reinstalled them**.

**Note:** use **expo** & **expo-modules-core** latest version.